# Update custom user fields programatically

Tags: 7, users

how can I update custom user fields programmatically?

I've tried this but don't know how to get Id because I have to execute this code automatically on page load ..

```
$existingUser = user_load($uid);
$edit = (array) $existingUser; 
$edit['field_company_name']['und'][0]['value'] = 'Ciklum';
user_save($existingUser, $edit);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
$existingUser = user_load($uid);
$existingUser -> field_company_name['und'][0]['value'] = "Ciklum";
user_save($existingUser);
```

Comment: the only issue that I'm facing is that I've many users. How can I update company name for a specific user?

Comment: Is there any way to load user with other matching condition?

Comment: @UmairYousaf You can by ex: `user_load(5)` put the UID number instead.

Comment: Thanx @No Sssweat . This approach is working for me. But it takes too much time for me to load a user with a specific Id because I don't know id's of user. Is there any way that I load a specific user by passing user's eamil address ?/

Comment: @Krishna Mohan is there any approach to load user with email address?

Comment: @UmairYousaf  you can load user by email like follows  `user_load_by_mail('umar@example.com')`;

Comment: I would encourage others using `entity_metadata_wrapper()`

Comment: Anybody knows why this works with spaces surronding the arrow between variable and field name `$existingUser -> field_company_name`?

Comment: @undersound I don't see any problem with that. It's just works fine. May be it's not a recommended as per coding conventions , but It works even the space exists.